# Eliminating Warning about simplexml_load_file PHP

Tags: php, xml, warnings

I first scan directory tree and retrieve data from xml files with `simplexml_load_file()`. The function work correctly, but I receive warning:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(startfolder/cyrilic) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\xxx.php on line 36

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "startfolder/cyrilic" in C:\xampp\htdocs\begin\xxx.php on line 36
```

This warning appears, when there have changing subfolder. 
I set in php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

The code is:

```
$dir    = 'startfolder';
        $items = glob($dir . '/*');
        $table = 'book';
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
             if (is_dir($items[$i])) {
                 $add = glob($items[$i] . '/*');
                 $items = array_merge($items, $add);
             }
         }
        echo "<ul id='booklist'>"."</n>";
        foreach ($items as $key=>$file){
            $url = $file;
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);  
            $book_count = count($xml->book);
```

Comment: Read the error message again - `failed to open stream: Permission denied`. It's a permission issue.

Comment: The operating system is Windows 7. This application was in another server WAMP and there didn't have a problem. Current server is XAMPP.

Comment: Okay, please post the code where you call `simplexml_load_file`.

Comment: Please do NOT set `allow_url_include` to ON. You do not need to include code from remote locations! Turn it off, it improves the security of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you can read the file first:

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$file){
    if(is_readable($file) == false) {
        echo "$file unreadable";
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: I can read the files. I display a result. I put this checking. It's OK.

Comment: Yes, but you are reading multiple files, and one of them cannot be opened. So if one file succeeds, and another fails, you still see "a" result, but also that warning. Solve the permissions issue with that file, or remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: There have problem when open only subdirectory. The contents and files are correct.